# Relaunch a cocoa app non-miniaturized that has been previously minimized and then closed

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nswindow

My Cocoa application somehow does not reopen non-minimized after having been minimized and then closed and restarted. In other projects, this behavior was not existent, so I'm a bit confused about what could cause this behavior.

The steps that produce this behavior:

- Launch the application
- Minimize it
- Close it (either by pressing the 'x' or cmd+q)
- Launch the application again

=> Now the app starts minimized, and I don't want this.

I have tried to deactivate the "Restorable" option in the Window .xib, but I do want to keep the position and size of the window.

Is there any convenient way to achieve relaunching a minimized application in a non-minimized state, without losing the dimensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the window's "Autosave" identifier in the XIB, something like "MainWindow" or whatever should be fine.  This tells User Defaults under what key to save the window's frame information in the application's preferences file.

As you mentioned, you still have to uncheck "Restorable" to prevent other state information from being saved.